# String Manipulation in a column

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Thinking about a data.frame lets say:

```
df <- data_frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), n = c("100+", "50+", "30+", "40+"))
```

Column `n` should be to converted to `c("100","50","30","40")` by using `str_replace()` within *dplyr* library.

I need something like this to work on:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(n = str_replace("+",""))
```

There must be a proper way to apply `str_replace()` function for a column with *dplyr*.

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass the column you want to perform the replacement on, and then escape the plus symbol.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(n = str_replace(n, "\\+",""))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks...